# How to print the column when another column met the condition

Tags: r, dataframe

Example Data

```
a <- c(1,2,2,3)
b <- c(1,2,3,4)
dat <- data.frame(a,b)
```

I would like to print the column 2 when any data from the column 1 is >=2

```
which(dat[,1]>=2)
```

This only show which row of column2 is greater than 2.
I expect it will show:

```
[1] 2 3 4
```

Sorry for my bad English and hope you can understand it.

Comment: I think you want `dat[dat$a > 2, 2]` or `dat$b[dat$a > 2]` or `with(dat, b[a > 2])`.

Comment: is it possible not to use dat$a ? I would like to use dat[,1]

Comment: Akrun gives one example, another is `dat[2][dat[1]>=2]`. Be careful using positional arguments as they are not as stable / clear as using names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need the corresponding values in 2nd column, use the `[`

```
dat[,2][dat[,1]>=2]
#[1] 2 3 4
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply. Sorry for my typo, I have already edited it. However, my expected output should be #[1] 2 3 4

Comment: @Alvin Your code already shows that `which(dat[,1] >=2)
#[1] 2 3 4`.  I am not sure what your expected output is now?

Comment: @Alvin Updated the post.  The values in your expected confused me

Comment: However, this output is the row number which met the requirement. I would like to print out the data in column 2 (b) i.e. 2 3 4

Comment: @Alvin It is printing the data in the column 2.  It just happened that your row number and the value in column 2 are the same here.  Change your 'b' and you will find it `b <- c(4, 5, 3, 2);
dat <- data.frame(a,b)`

Comment: really appreciate for your help! was replying ur previous post